# Is it possible to use React-intl as variable in?

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, react-helmet

I'm using `react-intl` and `react-helmet` ! and i'm trying to pass a meta description to Helmet as translation text but it seems that is not possible !

Here is what i did:

```
<Helmet
     meta={[{ name: 'description', content: { id: 'homepage.description'} }]}
     link={[{ rel: 'icon', href: 'favicon/favicon-32x32.png' }]}
/>
```

the `homepage.description` is a text on `lang/en/en.json` .

I guess If the translations can be grabbed and used as variable it can be easy to use, i'll do it just like this :

```
render() {
    const description = formatMessage({ id: 'homepage.description', values: {country: 'Morocco'} });
    return (
        <Helmet
              title={pageTitle}
              meta={[{ name: 'description', content:  {{description}} }]}
              link={[{ rel: 'icon', href: 'favicon/favicon-32x32.png' }]}
            />
    );
}
```

If this even possible ? or does exists any alternative to this or best practice please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know its late but I am stuck with react-intl.....so how have you defined your description text in en.json file. so that It accepts dynamic varibale.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible if you use injectIntl, this way you can get a translated string and use whenever is needed:

```
import {injectIntl} from 'react-intl';

...
render() {
    const intl = this.props.intl;
    const description = intl.formatMessage({ id: 'homepage.description', values: {country: 'Morocco'} });
    return (
        <Helmet
              title={pageTitle}
              meta={[{ name: 'description', content:  {{description}} }]}
              link={[{ rel: 'icon', href: 'favicon/favicon-32x32.png' }]}
            />
    );
}
...

export default injectIntl(YourComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can simply do:

```
const Example = injectIntl( ({ intl }) => {
   return (
      <MyComponentt propExampple={ intl.formatMessage({ id: 'translation-ID' }) } />
   )
} );
```